# wcscmp - Access violation while using this function

Tags: c, winapi

Basically, I was trying to compare the `*PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO spi` (its ImageName field) with a string using `wcsmp` as follows :

```
if (wcscmp(L"Test.exe", spi->ImageName.Buffer))
```

This seems to give me an access violation error. Also from what I know, ImageName is of the type `UNICODE_STRING` and `UNICODE_STRING` structure uses `PWSTR` for the Buffer field. So is it right to compare 2 `PWSTR` using `wcscmp`? If not what are the alternatives to compare the `spi->ImageName.Buffer` to a string in C?

Comment: One possibility is that either `spi` or `Buffer` is a NULL pointer.

Comment: If you catch the crash in a debugger, is the location in your code where you think it is? And what is the values of all involved variables when the crash happens?

Comment: you need use [`RtlEqualUnicodeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlequalunicodestring) instead `wcscmp` here. and in first element `spi->ImageName.Buffer` is always 0

Comment: `wcscmp` is for null-terminated strings. and the second argument that you pass is not null-terminated

Comment: As an extension to the posts already here, if you plan on doing this one day in kernel-mode using routines like NtQuerySystemInformation, it is not always "safe". You will not have a lock and thus the data you try to access with the structure (e.g. a pointer to the SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure) can change even whilst you're enumerating it, and thus could land you into a crash. Therefore, it is safer to let user-mode handle this, and just exchange results unless you truly need to do it in kernel-mode.

Comment: So under those circumstances, it would be a better idea to monitor process creation via PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine/Ex/Ex2 and keep your own table of running processes (you can link up additional information like the process name, image path on disk, etc.), and just remove entries when the callback is invoked for termination for a process on your cache list. This is better than using Zw/NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemProcessInformation on-demand for the reasons I explained in the above comment. However only really applicable if your driver starts early and stays active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wcscmp()` expects null-terminated strings, but the `ImageName` is a `UNICODE_STRING`, which is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.  It has a `Length` member to indicate how many bytes it contains (divide that by `sizeof(WCHAR)` to get the number of characters).

You can use [`wcsncmp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eywx8zcx.aspx) instead:

```
if (wcsncmp(L"Test.exe", spi->ImageName.Buffer, spi->ImageName.Length / sizeof(WCHAR)))
```

Otherwise, use [`RtlEqualUnicodeString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlequalunicodestring) instead:

```
UNICODE_STRING fileName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"Test.exe");
if (!RtlEqualUnicodeString(&fileName, &(spi->ImageName), FALSE))
```

Comment: I just ignored the first entry where spi->ImageName.Buffer = NULL and then used wcscmp with the rest, seems to work fine, I'll switch it around with this, if it makes the application more robust!

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion -instead of ignoring first entry - why not use only correct `RtlEqualUnicodeString` ? in concrete case `wcsncmp` will be work ok, but in general case - no, because `UNICODE_STRING` can have 0 symbols inside string

Comment: `wcsncmp()` can handle NULL input.  A NULL string pointer is treated as a string with a length of 0 chars.

Comment: @remy RbMm means that the UNICODE_STRING contains null characters that are not terminators.

Comment: yes, i mean exactly this (0 characters inside string). as result in general case - `wcsncmp` can not correct handle `UNICODE_STRING` because it stop on first 0 characters. but in concrete case - when string containing process name - this never happens

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was referring to TotalAnime's comment about skipping `ImageName.Buffer == NULL`, not RbMm's comment about `UNICODE_STRING` containing nul characters

Answer (score 3):

for compare `UNICODE_STRING` need use [`RtlEqualUnicodeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlequalunicodestring) function, if we need use only ==, !=, or [`RtlCompareUnicodeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708867(v=vs.85).aspx) if need >,<,= . in general case `UNICODE_STRING` can be not 0 terminating, containing 0 internally or have  `Buffer == 0` - this is exactly your case (first element of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` array containing `UNICODE_STRING` with all 0).

so code for compare names can look like:

```
static const UNICODE_STRING Test = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"Test.exe");
RtlEqualUnicodeString(&Test, &pspi->ImageName, TRUE);
```

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion - only by some error in your code. not in my answer