# Access violation when reading buffer of UNICODE_STRING

Tags: c++, winapi, credential-providers

I have written a custom credential provider that uses a KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON structure.
Now that everything works fine I tried to write some unittests (I know that tests should be written before coding, but in this case I had to figure out how everything works first ;-)).

When I try to assert the contents of the KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON structure by using the solution to [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834656/wcscmp-access-violation-while-using-this-function) with wcsncmp like this:

```
KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* kerbCertificateLogon = reinterpret_cast<KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON*>(serializedCredentials->rgbSerialization);
wcsncmp(domainName, kerbCertificateLogon->DomainName.Buffer, kerbCertificateLogon->DomainName.Length / sizeof(wchar_t));
```

I get an access violation in wcsncmp at this point:

```
    extern "C" int __cdecl wcsncmp(
    wchar_t const* a,
    wchar_t const* b,
    size_t         count
    )
{
    if (count == 0)
        return 0;

    while (--count != 0 && *a && *a == *b) // <== Here comes "read access violation b was 0x48"
    {
        ++a;
        ++b;
    }

    return static_cast<int>(*a - *b);
}
```

Furthermore when debugging the function filling the buffer I can see in the "Locals"-view of visual studio directly after filling the buffer with this code:

```
kerbCertificateLogon->DomainName.Buffer = reinterpret_cast<PWSTR>(domainBuffer - authInfo);
```

this result:

> 0x0000000000000048 <Error reading characters of string.>

WTF??? The same code works fine when used by LSA, so I think that everythings alright, but why can't I read the value in a simple unittest?

Comment: What is `domainBuffer`? What is `authInfo`? How are they related? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? And while the crash might happen in a library function, the root cause is not in the function.

Comment: I know about the mcve. In this case this could be difficult because a credential provider cannot be boiled down to some lines of code that are complete. The complete construction of the KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGN can be found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869313/how-to-write-a-ksp-to-hook-up-into-kerb-certificate-logon)

Comment: you need use [`RtlEqualUnicodeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlequalunicodestring) (if need only == and !=) or [`RtlCompareUnicodeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlcompareunicodestring) (if need > <  too) when working with `UNICODE_STRING`

Comment: I have read about that, but I did not want to install the driver kit just for unittesting and cannot find the wdm.h elsewhere.

Comment: Constructing a [mcve] is pretty simple. You don't need any of your certificate structures. You can reproduce the issue by crafting 2 `UNICODE_STRING` objects that resemble your input to `wcsncmp`.

Comment: You can get the source of [`RtlEqualUnicodeString from Wine`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/c5bb1084844ce94a841e218dc0b64e7d8ed13f34/dlls/ntdll/rtlstr.c#L513). It's just a dozen lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as usual I found the solution shortly after asking.
Contrary to one of the comments above the error had to to with the certificate structures! So just using two UNICODE_STRING would not have worked to reproduce the issue.

Inside of these structures **relative** pointers are used to store information as could have been seen from the link to the older question.

I just didn't see the wood for the trees.

So the solution is quite simple: instead of directly using the pointer to the buffer in the UNICODE_STRING I had to recalculate the absolute pointer. I extracted this to a method because I need this comparison quite often in my tests:

```
static void AssertRelativeUnicodeStringEquals(const wchar_t* expected, UNICODE_STRING actual, LPBYTE basePointer)
{
    const int result = wcscmp(expected, reinterpret_cast<PWSTR>(basePointer + reinterpret_cast<int>(actual.Buffer)));
    EXPECT_EQ(0, result);
}
```

This I can now call with:

```
AssertRelativeUnicodeStringEquals(domainName, kerbCertificateLogon->DomainName, (LPBYTE)kerbCertificateLogon);
```